# how to run a javascript code on an external website?

Tags: javascript, web

I've written a script by JavaScript and i'm running it on external websites (which that I don't own their domain such as Google or Stackoverflow) by opening the Inspector (<kbd>F12</kbd>), paste and run the script in the console.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to run the code without doing above steps ?
2. In some cases I click on a button and a new page would be load. How can I load that script on second page too ?

Comment: Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey or some other userscript manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method would be to install a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/). If you paste your code into a userscript, it'll run automatically on any sites that match the `@include` / `@match` directive of the metadata block.

> In some cases I click on a button and a new page would be load . how can I load that script on second page too ?

If possible, put the URL of that second page into the metadata block of your userscript.

For an example of a userscript that runs on multiple pages:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Some example
// @include          /^https://www\.google\.com*/
// @include          /^http://.example\.com/
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('script running');
```

If you go to google.com and search for `example.com`, you'll see `script running`. Then if you click on the search result to `example.com`, you'll see `script running` on the other page too.

If the other URL isn't known in advance, it'll be harder. You'll probably need

```
// @match        *://*/*
```

(to have the script run on *all* pages) and somehow communicate to the new window that it should run the script as well, such as through a query string, or `postMessage`, or `GM_setValue`.